# async.js - async.map does not return any value

Tags: javascript, jquery, async.js

I have a problem when I am using the async library. 
My aim is to be able to execute function requests in parallel, for this I am using the async library. In my code I am creating an array of functions which thebn has to be called in parallel using async.map. I have a problem when I want to read the return value from my async task.

Here the code snippet:

```
  var pages = Math.ceil(rowCount/config.ROWS_PER_PAGE);
  var func = [];
  var top, left, wdith, height;
  for(var i=0; i<=pages;i++) {
      top = i * config.ROWS_PER_PAGE;
      left = 0;
      width = config.DATA_PER_ROW;
      height = Math.min(config.ROWS_PER_PAGE, rowCount - i * config.ROWS_PER_PAGE); 
      var ff = makeCallbackFunc(top, left, width, height);
      func.push(ff(function () {return true;}));
   }

  async.map(
    func,
        function(err, results){  
            //???? Can not read the results output here!!??                        
            console.log('all calls called without any errors');
        });

  function makeCallbackFunc(top, left, width, height) {
    return function (callback) {
    console.log('top: ' + top + 'left: ' + left + 'width: ' + width + 'height: ' + height);
    return backendApi.getData([{
        qTop: top,
        qLeft: left,
        qWidth: width,
        qHeight: height
      }]);

    };
  }
```

This is the output using console.log(results);

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why this outputs anything at all…

Comment: Why are you never calling `callback`? Why are you passing `function () {return true;}`? Where is `func` declared? Why do you not pass an array and an iterator function to `async.map` as required by the docs? Any chance you actually wanted to use [`async.parallel`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) instead?

Comment: I updated the code with the missing parts, func is an array of functions, which I am passing in the async.map function. The part regarding function() {return true;} is the one I have copied from an example, if i remove this part it will not iterate through all the functions call. The problem is that i can not read the return value, maybe i am missing a callback ? I am rather new in JS so not a professional :-).

Comment: Maybe you should first learn about callbacks in general, how they work and where you need them, before trying to use async.js.